# How to enable pub/sub ordering key in firebase function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I notice that when I create a firebase function with a pub/sub trigger, the subscription that is being generated is having the ordering message as disabled. How can I enabled it? I cant see any option or parameter from the `firebase-functions`

```
exports.foo = functions
  .region(region)
  .pubsub.topic(topicName)
  .onPublish((message: Message) => {
}
```

[image]

Comment: I also tried to look at the `firebase-functions/v2`, but I still dont see any message ordering parameter.

Comment: Message ordering is enabled when the subscription is created.

Comment: @JohnHanley so do you mean that this is unachievable with the current `firebase functions` ? since the subscription is created automatically when I deploy my function?

Comment: What is creating the subscription? Add more details and context to your post.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780310/firebase-pubsub-trigger-with-message-ordering

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thank you. sad that this feature is not supported yet.

Comment: Correct, the feature is not supported. The solution is to deploy an HTTP function and to create a PubSub push subscription, with the ordering key feature (and other, like filtering only available when you create your subscription separately), and as target URL, the HTTP function to invoke.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you for your suggestion, but currently that is not the path that I want to take. if I create a http function, I need to consider the authentication also. maybe I will use GKE for now. thank you for the suggestion anyway

Comment: GKE??? Ok, fine, but authentication will be still a concern, and the overhead to simply deploy a function is super huge! Good luck!

Comment: originally, my pub/sub consumer was in the GKE already. just that since its only triggered around 2-3 times/day but I still have to pay for 24H, its quite expensive. so i was planning to move it to cloud function to save money. thank you for your help tho! cheers  

Comment: Hi @Mark, Could you add your resolution steps as the answer to the question?

Comment: hi @PrajnaRaiT as mentioned by others, there is no good answer for now. all of the current workaround still have a downside / side concern. For me, i did it with GKE since I already had a GKE system. but the downside is the cost and the setup. So my solution, is not a recommended for others

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Stack Overflow link shared by @Renaud Tarnec.

Currently, it is not possible to set the ordering setting in Pub/Sub using the Firebase CLI.

As an workaround, you can switch to use gcloud to establish the [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) and create its [pubsub topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering#enabling_message_ordering) with your customizations.

For more information you can refer to this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780310/firebase-pubsub-trigger-with-message-ordering/70781011#70781011).

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.